# How to use angular material api services?

Tags: javascript, angular, web

I am a beginner to the angular world, I was using the angular material's "Sort header" component, and on the API tab (https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api) there is something called services, and I want to use them, But I don't get it how do to use it.

For example:

On the API tab of "Sort header" or (https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api)

I want to use the service "MatSortHeaderIntl",
it has some properties such as - sortDescriptionLabel

So please tell me how to use "sortDescriptionLabel" property of "MatSortHeaderIntl" service.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import, and provide it to your module

```
import {MatSortHeaderIntl} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
       ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [..],
  declarations: [...],
  bootstrap: [...],
  providers: [MatSortHeaderIntl]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then in whatever component you want to use it, instantiate it

```
constructor( private matSortService: MatSortHeaderIntl) {}
```

and you can call it by scope

```
this.matSortService.<method>
```

[I setup an example of Integrated MatSortHeaderIntl Service](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqlqud)

Comment: How can I use interfaces, like I want to use `ViewportScrollPosition` interface. Docs https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api#ViewportScrollPosition